# Finding the all possible values of $x$ such that $\tan^{-1}(x+1) + \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(x-1) = \tan^{-1}(3)$

Tags: inverse

Find possible value of $x$ such that

$$\tan^{-1}(x+1) + \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(x-1) = \tan^{-1}(3)$$

Progress: what I did was to consider a case when $x^2 -1 < 1$ $(xy < 1)$ and $3x>-1$ $(xy > -1)$ and then apply $\tan^{-1}(x) \pm tan^{-1}(y)$ identity and got the range.

But is it correct to say we got all the possible value of $x$ or we need to consider all possibilities of $x^2 - 1 > 1$ , $3x < -1$ etc?

As what my book did was just did the first case and then left it without telling what about the solutions from other cases of $tan^{-1}(x) \pm \tan^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: **Hint** you cannot have more one root (whatever can be the rhs). The derivative of the lhs is always positive.

Comment: How can you say that i mean can it be said easily without taking derivative ?  Oh i think because sum of three strictly increasing functions is an increasing function? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: But still we have to check all three roots that we got isnt @ClaudeLeibovici by the solution given below ?

Comment: You got it. There one and only one root (at least in the real domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to consider cases.

Think first that you are looking for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x+1) + \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(x-1) -k$$ the first derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^2}=\frac {3 x^4+6 x^2+8 } {\left(x^2+1\right) \left(x^2-2 x+2\right) \left(x^2+2 x+2\right) }$$ is always positive; so, whatever is $k$, there is only one root.

$$k=\tan^{-1}(3)\implies f(0)=-\tan^{-1}(3)<0\quad \text{and}\quad f(1)=\frac{\pi }{4}-\cot ^{-1}(7)>0$$ So, the solution is $\in (0,1)$.

If you do not want to make anything complex, expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x=0$

$$f(x)=-\tan ^{-1}(3)+2 x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Using the expansion to $O\left(x^3\right)$, the simplest estimate is
$$x_0 \sim \frac 12 \tan ^{-1}(3) =0.624523$$ while the exact solution is $5-\sqrt{19}=0.641101$.

If you already now about series reversion, using the expansion to $O\left(x^5\right)$ gives
$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(f(x)+\tan ^{-1}(3)\right)+\frac{1}{96} \left(f(x)+\tan
   ^{-1}(3)\right)^3+O\left(\left(f(x)+\tan ^{-1}(3)\right)^5\right)$$ and since we want $f(x)=0$, then the estimate
$$x=\frac{1}{96} \tan ^{-1}(3) \left(48+\tan ^{-1}(3)^2\right)=0.644821$$

Comment: This is really what i was looking for , amazing method and explanation !!

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to apply the identity

\begin{align*}
\tan(a + b + c) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b) + \tan(c) - \tan(a)\tan(b)\tan(c)}{1 - \tan(a)\tan(b) - \tan(a)\tan(c) - \tan(b)\tan(c)}
\end{align*}

so that you arrive at the following equation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3x  - x(x^{2} - 1)}{1 - (x^{2} - 1) - 2x^{2}} = 3 & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x^{3} - 4x}{3x^{2} - 2} = 3\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{3} - 9x^{2} - 4x + 6  = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{3} + x^{2}) - 10(x^{2} + x) + 6(x + 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}(x^{2} + 1) - 10x(x + 1) + 6(x + 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} - 10x + 6)(x + 1) = 0
\end{align*}

Hence the solution set is a subset of $S = \{5\pm\sqrt{19},-1\}$.

**EDIT**

It remains to determine if there are extraneous roots.

In order to do so, you can check out WolframAlpha (for example).

Comment: +1 That looks like a good answer, but that is *barely* a hint!

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for the comment. Should I remove the hint title?

Comment: Actually book method was like i did taking tan^-13 - tan^-1y and tan^-1(x-1) + tan^-1(x+1) apply formula both sides

Comment: @Orien_Pax (I guess) the method proposed in the book is based on the assumption the student does not know the $\tan$ identity of the sum of three arcs. If that is indeed the case, you can proceed as you suggested as well.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I'd just finish it off, personally. You're almost there, and the final steps are routine. If I were writing it for the first time, I'd probably end it at $$\frac{3x  - x(x^{2} - 1)}{1 - (x^{2} - 1) - 2x^{2}} = 3,$$ or possibly just the $\tan$ angle sum identity, and call it a hint. But that's me, and I tend to have different standards to the community at large. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit I will take your comment into consideration and finish the exercise. Thanks for the feedback by the way :)

Comment: But my doubt is the cases of xy>1<-1 etc as the book  consider only one of them

Comment: Shouldnt we need to check for all the possibilities in that tan^-1 x+- tan^-1 y formula?

Comment: I see okay so steps being arrived same in both is why you considered this okay fine

Comment: No, it's not equivalent when you take the tangent of both sides: it could introduce extraneous solutions where the difference between the two sides is a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Just one more thing putting x= -1 and 5+√19 seems like not satisfying the equation can you check ?

Comment: Exactly @DanielSchepler i was thinking that only , it was just a coincidence in this problem otherwise not true , how will you solve if you go by my method , will you take all possible cases where the book dealt with just one case ?

Comment: Well, if you do have a solution, then taking tangents of both sides will still result in a correct equation, so $x\in \{ -1, 5 \pm \sqrt{19} \}$.  Then from there, you can plug in, or at least do a rough estimate of the arctangents which is accurate enough to determine whether the difference between the two sides in the original equation is 0, $\pi$, $-\pi$, $2\pi$, $-2\pi$, etc.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia check my previous comment

Comment: @DanielSchepler is there any other method we can apply for this problem ? And my method of using tan^-1 (x+1) - tan^-1 (x-1) = tan^-3 - tan^-1 x and applying tan^-1x +-tan^-1(y) formula both sides is too lengthy because we need to take many cases like x^2-1><1 and 3x><-1 right?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\tan\big(\arctan x+\arctan y\big)\equiv\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$ and $\arctan$ has principal range $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right),$ thus, for each $(x,y)$ and some $k\in\{-1,0,1\},$ $$\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)+k\pi.$$

Therefore, \begin{align}&\arctan(x+1) + \arctan(x) + \arctan(x-1) = \arctan(3)\\
\implies&\arctan\left(\frac{x^3-4x}{3x^2-2}\right)=\arctan3+n\pi\quad\text{for some }n\in\{-2,-1,\ldots,2\}\\
\implies&\frac{x^3-4x}{3x^2-2}=3\\
\implies&\cdots\\
\implies&x=-1\:\:\text{or}\:\:5\pm\sqrt{19}\end{align}

$5-\sqrt{19}$ is the only non-extraneous solution. [Desmos check](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bwfqpynvw9).

Comment: [As requested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409792/how-to-handle-all-cases-imposed-on-x-so-as-to-solve-sin2-cos-1-cot2/4411999?noredirect=1#comment9232115_4411999).